# VIM Restore last search pattern

Tags: vim

I remapped `[[` and `]]` to find the previous and next pattern in the file.  The mappings are as follows:

```
nmap [[ ?^.section <CR>
nmap ]] /?section /<CR>
```

The issue is that when I use any of them, I "loose" the current search pattern, so when doing `n` for the next match, I search for the next "section".

Is there a way to restore the search pattern, or for the `[[` and `]]` mappings to not affect the current search pattern?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can probably do it by hand by saving and restoring the `"/` register. However, a better way is to just move your code into a function; returning from a function automatically restores it. To quote the VIM documentation:

> *function-search-undo*
>   The last used search pattern and the redo command "."
>   will not be changed by the function.  This also
>   implies that the effect of |:nohlsearch| is undone
>   when the function returns.

This would look something like this in your `.vimrc`:

```
function! Ayman_NextSection
    /?section /
endfunction
nmap ]] call Ayman_NextSection()<CR>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do `histdel()` might be helpful as well. This automatically clears your current search, but does not remove the search from the search history (accessed with `q/`)

Comment: Is it possible to push/pop the search register in similar way while recording a macro?

Answer (score 2):

After typing '/' or '?' for begin the search, just use up-down arrow to bring the search buffer line by line.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the function `search()` because it will not mess with your search register:

```
:call search('pattern')
:call search('pattern', 'b')
```

The flag `b` means, search backward instead of forward