# Vim - Commands to visually select a regex match?

Tags: vim

Can't figure out how to automatically select a regex match in visual mode.

For example, manually, I could search for a word

```
/word
```

It lands the cursor on the first character of the match "word".
Then I press `v` to enter Visual mode, and press `llll` to select the whole "word".

Now I want to do this by a macro, and I don't know the length of the match ahead of time.

I expected that Vim would automatically define some built-in marks at the beginning and end of the current match, so that I could ` to them. But I couldn't find any information on that.

What I want is to reassign `Ctrl+n` to a macro to take me to the next match and select it in visual mode, i.e. not just highlight the match. (To parallel how `n` takes you to the next match.)

If you're wondering why, its because I want to create folds based on regex matches (like `Ctrl+n`, `zf`), but I'm sure it will come in handy in other cases too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
:noremap <C-n> //s<CR>v//e+1<CR>
```

Edit summary: was //e, but //e+1 worked for me (selected the last character of the match too).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed (except trial and error showed that `//e+1` took me to the boundary after the last char of the match; edited). Neat! After failing to find it myself, I was expecting that it would be tricky to do what I want.

Comment: Right, I see. When the `'selection'` option is set to `inclusive`, then `//e` works in the above. When it is set to `exclusive`, then `//e+1` works. I use `:behave mswin` which sets `'selection'` to `exclusive`.

Answer (score 7):

//e takes you to the end character of last search.
More info -- :help {offset}.

You can find how to restore old search buffer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385196/vim-restore-last-search-pattern).

Comment: This worked wonderfully, for me, thank you.  The noremap thing didn't work (or perhaps it wasn't in the way I needed?)

Answer (score 7):

For the benefit of folks who stumble across this question in the future, vim now has this feature built-in: `gn` (and its close sibling `gN`) will jump to the next (respectively, previous) match and visually select it. It can also be used as a motion; e.g. `cgn` will jump to the next match and change it.